# Android SDK: Parsing JSON from URL using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to parse JSON from a URL to then add data to an array.
I am using the GSON library.

My JSON has the following format:

```
[
   {
      "img-src":"http://website.com/images/img1.png",
      "URL":"http://google.com"
   },
   {
      "img-src":"http://website.com/images/img2.jpg",
      "URL":"http://yahoo.com"
   }
]
```

I want to grab the above data in a separate thread, I have the following code:

```
public class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



            return null;
        }


    }
```

How do I go about grabbing each "img-src" and "URL" values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this method to fetch your Data in an Array list

```
 public ArrayList<NewsItem> getNews(String url) {
    ArrayList<NewsItem> data = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();

    java.lang.reflect.Type arrayListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<NewsItem>>(){}.getType();
    gson = new Gson();

    httpClient = WebServiceUtils.getHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
        data = gson.fromJson(reader, arrayListType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("json array","While getting server response server generate error. ");
    }
    return data;
}
```

This should be how you should declare your ArrayList Type class (here its NewsItem)

```
  import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
    public class NewsItem   {

@SerializedName("title")
public String title;

@SerializedName("content")
public String title_details;

@SerializedName("date")
public  String date;

@SerializedName("featured")
public String imgRawUrl; 


}
```

Here is the WebSErvice Util Class.

```
public class WebServiceUtils {

 public static HttpClient getHttpClient(){
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        int timeoutConnection = 50000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 50000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);           
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);          
        return httpclient;
     }

}
```

Comment: where you will be using @SerializedName("img-src") and @SerializedName("URL") to fill your class variables (here the class is NewsItem)

Comment: where do I get the WebServiceUtils class?

Comment: I have editted the post for you, so that you can have a look at the WebServiceUtil Class

Answer (score 0):

That's the code I use (working well for me).

```
//Initialize the list
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourObject>>(){}.getType();
//Parse
List<YourObject> List= new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
```

YourObject should be something like :

```
public class Category {
    private String URL;
    private String img-src;

    public Category(String URL, String img-src){
        this.URL= URL;
        this.img-src= img-src;
    }
}
```

Regards.

Ps: With this you will obtain a list of "YourObject". Then you can create to list one with the URL and other with img-src

Comment: i'm not sure how to get the values themselves though, for example the "img-src" values should be added to one list and the "URL" values should be added to another list

Comment: right but I don't know why I need another class, is it not possible/quicker to just download the data and add it to an ArrayList?

Comment: @user1417302 I'm not sure. I had the same problem has you and I found not another way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In this user guide you can find a lot of examples:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: i've seen this user guide but unfortunately there is too much information there for a beginner

Comment: @user1417302 First — [I (pronoun)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(pronoun)). Second, you should do your job. "too much information" is not an acceptable reason.

Comment: I disagree @Lincoln Hawk. Maybe half of all SO questions come from people who don't have the time or patience to go through the documentation files of their tools, and need a quick answer. That's just a *normal* behaviour